# SerializationException Because of security restrictions, the type System.Runtime.Remoting.ObjRef cannot be accessed

Tags: .net, iis, remoting

I have a remoting server hosted under IIS that is throws the following exception when I try and talk to it SerializationException Because of security restrictions, the type System.Runtime.Remoting.ObjRef cannot be accessed.
If I host the server in my own exe I don't have any issues.
Searching Google, the solution for most people is to set typeFilterLevel="Full"

```
<clientProviders>
    <formatter ref="binary" typeFilterLevel="Full"/>
</clientProviders>    
<serverProviders>
     <formatter ref="binary" typeFilterLevel="Full"/>
</serverProviders>
```

Which I am doing.

I am also setting trust level to full which should the the default anyway.

```
<system.web>
    <authentication mode="None" />
    <customErrors mode="Off" />
    <compilation defaultLanguage="c#" />
    <trust level="Full"/>
</system.web>
```

I am using IIS 6.0 on Windows 2003.  The code compilied for .NET 2.0.  The application pool is running under an account with administrative permissions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem ended up being a bad channel definition.  The serverProviders tag was not inside a channel,  the indentation of the xml made it look like it was.